# Are GitHub Issue Comment IDs Unique?

Tags: mysql, github, unique, auto-increment, issue-tracking

### Intro/Scenario

We use GitHub issues to manage our "bug-tracking" and "feature backlog". 
We are writing a script to "backup" the GitHub issues 
so that they are "available" if (*when*) GitHub is "down" ...

> see: https://github.com/dwyl/github-backup

We are using the **API** / **WebHooks** to get the data from GitHub, 
but we have a question which will inform our Database Schema for *storing* the Issues and their related *comments*.

### Question

Is the `id` of an issue and the `id` of the issue's *comments* 
*unique* across GitHub (*e.g: an auto-incrementing INT*)
or are they only *unique* to the repository in which they were created?

For example: we can see the `id` of an **issue comment** when we *link* to it: 
[https://github.com/dwyl/github-backup/issues/37#issuecomment-**369581775**](https://github.com/dwyl/github-backup/issues/37#issuecomment-369581775) 
is the `id` (*in this case*) **`369581775`** ***globally* unique** across GitHub?

Comment: Did you find answer? =)

Comment: @RuslanAbelharisov sadly, not. If you do discover it, please share!